Automate cookie syncing in Postman with Postman Interceptor
We use Postman to test our web services and we obviously need session (auth/login) cookies, which we currently copy manually with Postman Interceptor / Devtools and then paste to Postman cookies.
Current workflow:

Login on our webapp
Copy required cookies with Postman Interceptor or manually in developer tools
Paste new cookies to cookie section in Postman
Test webservices, endpoints, etc.
If new session/cookies are needed, start again with first step

To improve our workflow we want to automate the cookie update in Postman when starting a new session by writing some pre-request scripts or similar. The script would intercept or fake (middleman) the login request in the browser and save the required response cookies in Postman automatically.
Improved workflow:

Login on webapp
(New scripts handle current workflow)
Test web services in postman
If new session/cookies are needed, start again with first step

Where could such scripts be written in Postman or how could such an improvement be approached?
Thanks <3
My considerations:

Intercept login request with Postman directly
Run side service which handles communication between website (login request) and Postman

